# Web API 2, Claims always null in my inheritance Apicontroller

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the Web API 2 Auth template in my project.I want to get the user id when the client request with API Key. My question is :

1. How can I get the API client user's Id.

- Is right or wrong resolve it through the API requesting?
- or take the `userId` in the http header directly?
- or query it from database using the API key?

2. I create the `MyApiController` inherit from `ApiController`, I want to get the claims in it.So I write some code in it. Like this

   ```
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
       { 
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        var principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        CorpId = (from c in principal.Claims where c.Type.Contains("CorpId") select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        UserId = (from c in principal.Claims where c.Type.Contains("UserId") select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
       }
   ```

I found the claim is null in the `MyApiController`, bit when I do it in the action controller, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather get request specific data when the request is executed (i.e. in Controller.Get method), not when the controller is created. Or use a filter attribute if values are not needed in controller method.